# How to fetch Device contacts and how to show individually

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i need to fetch all contacts from device and want to show individually accordingly ..kindly have a look my code thanks

```
// using method to fetch contacts from device 
-(void)fetchContacts{
CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];
     if( status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
          NSLog(@"access denied");
     }else{
          CNContactStore *contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
          NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys, nil];
          CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keys];
          request.predicate = nil;
          [contactStore enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:nil usingBlock:^(CNContact* __nonnull contact, BOOL* __nonnull stop){
               NSString *phoneNumber = @"";
               if( contact.phoneNumbers)
                    phoneNumber = [[[contact.phoneNumbers firstObject] value] stringValue];
               NSMutableDictionary *contactValue=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
               if ([contact.givenName isEqualToString:@""]) {
               }else{
                    [contactValue setValue:phoneNumber forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
                    [contactValue setObject:contact.givenName forKey:@"userName"];
                    [contactValue setObject:contact.familyName forKey:@"familyName"];
                    [contactValue setObject:[contact.emailAddresses valueForKey:@"value"]  ?:@"" forKey:@"emailAddress"];
                    [contactValue setObject:contact.identifier forKey:@"phoneIdentifier"];

               }
               [_totalContact addObject:contactValue];
          }];
}
```

Comment: Please formate you code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Contacts framework for that.

```
 CNContactStore *cnContactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];



    [cnContactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {



        if (granted == YES) {



            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];



            NSString *containerId = cnContactStore.defaultContainerIdentifier;



            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];



            NSError *error;



          _contactDetailArray = [cnContactStore unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];



            if (error) {



                NSLog(@”error fetching contacts %@”, error);



            } else {

                //Do Something



            }
}

}];
```

For Complete code please visit my [blog](https://iostpoint.wordpress.com/2016/08/11/get-a-list-of-all-contacts-in-ios-using-contacts-framework/)